# Raspberry Pi 5 - linux-headers kept back

Tags: raspberry-pi, linux-kernel

I don't have any packages on hold, but doing apt-get update and upgrade shows the following output, are these packages being held back from the OS itself? thanks.

```
pamanes@rpi5:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
pamanes@rpi5:~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-headers-rpi-2712 linux-headers-rpi-v8 linux-image-rpi-2712 linux-image-rpi-v8
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/601